# mongodb query to get record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have documents saved in MongoDB with an integer value "version" field.

```
   DocumentType {
      ... other fields ...
      "version": int
   }

   List<MyDocumentType> getDocumentByVersion(int versionNumber){
      // need to get 2 documents
      //  1. "version": versionNumber
      //  2. the last version of the document
   }
```

How to efficiently write the query?

Comment: There's not enough information about your schema here for a complete answer, but the concept is you want to retrieve the document with the highest version number, right?

Comment: @robinsax Yes, the highest version number, AND the specified version number, I need to get two documents in one query.